# Floats(in bootstrap), why is this working like that?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, this code works fantastic:

[image: good one]

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="page-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Ribbit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Treehouse</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Ribbit</h3>
  </header>

  <div>
    <h1>Self-destructing message app</h1>
    <p>Learn how to build this fun little app by signing up for a Treehouse account today! We'll teach you how to build both apps from scratch!</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Download the app</a>
      <a href="#" >Text me the link</a>
    </p> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>&copy; 2013 Ribbit - By Treehouse Island, Inc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I put the `<h3>Ribbit</h3>` above the `<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">` it's looking like this. Why is this happening? Can somebody explain me?

[image: wrong]

```
<header class="page-header">
   <h3>Ribbit</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Ribbit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Treehouse</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `ul` comes before the `h3`, it floats to the right and the `h3` makes room for it, moving into the space the `ul` would otherwise have occupied.  When it instantiates *beneath* the `h3` (which does not float), it only stays as high up on the page as where it would have been had it not been floated.

From MDN (emphasis mine):

> ...when an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the document. It is shifted **to the left or right** until it touches the edge of it's containing box or another floated element

So, elements are pulled from normal flow and shifted only left or right.  Other non-floated elements consume the space which remains.

**EDIT:** If you need the `h3` above the `ul`, float it to the left (and contain them both if needed) like so:

```
<header class="page-header clearfix">
  <h3 class="pull-left">Ribbit</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Ribbit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Treehouse</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```